# How to return multiple results from an Excel plugin function?

Tags: excel, plugins

I'm trying to write an Excel plugin function. Below is the code.

```
    [ExcelFunction(Description = "Get regular expression matches.")]
    public static object RegexExtractAll([ExcelArgument("Input string")]string input,
        [ExcelArgument("Regex Pattern")] string pattern)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
        MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);

        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            result.Add(match.Value);
        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

However, when I use the function in Excel, only the first matched value was found and inserted in the currently selected cell. In my example, there should have two matches `writes` and `notes`. The expected behavior is that Excel automatically expands the range and select two cells and fill them with the matched result `writes` and `notes`. How can I do that? I put the Visual Studio project in DropBox and you can download it from https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cr79i3ajxkf09d/Excel-Regex-master.rar?dl=1

[image]

Comment: I can't download your code atm, but maybe you want to consider returning your array as a string eg `return Arrays.toString(result.ToArray());`